# SQL script to extract country from free text field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, parsing, freetext

I'm trying to create a SQL UDF or statement to parse a free text field and find the country name from it, but I'm unable to do so successfully.

To give you guys the full context, I've got a transactions table (tbltransactions below) which contains transaction details and one of the fields is this free text field. This should *ideally* contain Payee name, Payee address and payee country (in that order). But as you'd expect with a free text field, there are all sorts of possible combinations. This also means that a country's name could be mis-spelt, abbreviated, shortened or missing completely. Fortunately, most transactions have countries specified in the end of the text block! There is another field in the table where the user enters a 3 character country code (mandatory). This may or may not match with what he entered in the free text field. Below is the dummy data in the table:

```
TransID     ISOCode BeneAddress
------------------- -----------
20          IRN     aaaa bb cccc Islamic Rupublic of Iran  
19          IRN     aaaa bb cccc Iran, Islamic Republic of
```

Now, I've made a look up table (tblCountryMappings) which stores a list of all countries and possible variations of their names (well  most of them!).

> Eg. 'Macedonia, Republic of', 'MACEDONIA,THE FORMER YUGOSLAV REPUBLIC
>   OF', 'MACEDONIA', 'MASEDONIA' etc.

Below is dummy data for this table:

```
ID  ISONumericCode  countryName                 matchIdentifier            matchIdentifierType
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
209  364            Iran, Islamic Republic of   IR                         ISOAlphaCode_2
210  364            Iran, Islamic Republic of   IRN                        ISOAlphaCode_3
495  364            Iran, Islamic Republic of   Iran                       Short_Name
1163 364            Iran, Islamic Republic of   Iran, Islamic Republic of  Original_Name
1309 364            Iran, Islamic Republic of   Islamic Rupublic of Iran   Alternate_Name
```

As you can see, there is a one to many mapping between the tables. The **objective** is to be able to analyse the transaction and find which country it was intended for (*primarily* based on the free-text field, not *just* the ISO code). For example, we should be able to see that Transaction 123 has “Iraq” in the ISO code, and “Iran” in the free text, and the free text match was on the ISO 3-character “IRN”. I also need to ensure that the matching works in boundary situations (e.g. end of line, surrounded by quotes), but not if it’s in the middle of a block of text (e.g. not matching the Saudi Arabia 2-character code “SA” to anyone called “Samuel”).

I've written this basic script to extract the last word from free-text and this could then be used to join matchIdentifier in tblCountryMappings but it obviously is an extremely poor attempt.

```
select 
    beneaddress
    ,SUBSTRING(beneaddress, 
               case when CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(beneaddress)) = 0 then 1 
                    else LEN(beneaddress) - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(beneaddress))))+2
               end
    ,LEN(beneaddress)) as Country
from
    tblTransactions
```

If you could please help me build this solution, it'll be really appreciated. Please pardon me if I've violated any rules of posting since this is my first time. Feel free to ask for further info and I'll post it at the earliest.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there is a perfect solution out there since I can imagine strange scenarios where individual street names or state names may be similar to certain country names. Having said that you can join your lookup table to the transaction table use `LIKE` statement. That way you can use regular expressions to match the country in the address. The country name will either be at the end or delimited at the front or end by either a ‘,’or space.  It should simplify your query somewhat but as I mentioned it won’t be perfect.

The following example shows what the query will look like.

```
DECLARE @tbltransactions TABLE
(
     TransID        INT
    ,ISOCode        NVARCHAR(3)
    ,BeneAddress    NVARCHAR(100)
)

DECLARE @tblCountryMappings TABLE
(
     ID                 INT IDENTITY
    ,CountryName        NVARCHAR(100)
    ,MatchIdentifier    NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @tbltransactions
(
     TransID    
    ,ISOCode    
    ,BeneAddress
)
VALUES
(1          ,'IRN'     ,'aaaa bb cccc Islamic Rupublic of Iran') ,
(2          ,'IRN'     ,'aaaa bb cccc "Iran", Islamic Republic of'),
(3          ,'IRN'     ,'aaRSAbb cccc IRN'),
(4          ,'IRN'     ,'aaaa bb cccc IR'),
(5          ,'IRN'     ,'aaaa bb cccc The Country of Fred')


INSERT INTO @tblCountryMappings
(       
     CountryName    
    ,MatchIdentifier
)
VALUES
('Iran, Islamic Republic of',   'IR'),         
('Iran, Islamic Republic of',   'IRN'),         
('Iran, Islamic Republic of',   'Iran'),
('South Africa, Republic of',   'RSA'),
('South Africa, Republic of',   'R.S.A.'),
('South Africa, Republic of',   'South Africa')


SELECT      T.TransID
            ,T.BeneAddress
            ,ISNULL(M.CountryName, '< Could not match country>') AS CountryName
            ,M.MatchIdentifier
FROM        @tbltransactions    T
LEFT OUTER JOIN @tblCountryMappings M ON 
                ( 
                        (T.BeneAddress LIKE '%[, "]' + M.MatchIdentifier + '[, "]%') -- Match any address which contains a word that start with a comma or space or quote ([, "]) and is then followed by the MatchIdentifier and then end with either a comma or space or quote.
                                OR
                        (T.BeneAddress LIKE '%[, "]' + M.MatchIdentifier ) -- Match any address which contains a word that start with a comma or space or quote ([, "]) and is then ends with the MatchIdentifier.
                                OR
                        (T.BeneAddress LIKE M.MatchIdentifier + '[, "]%') -- Match any address which contains a word that start with the MatchIdentifier and then end with either a comma or space or quote.
                                OR
                        (T.BeneAddress LIKE M.MatchIdentifier ) -- Match the address with an exact match of the MatchIdentifier
                )
```

In the above example sql will match the BeneAddress with regular expression generated based on the value of the MatchIdentifier field.

Example in the tblCountryMappings the MatchIdentifier field will have the following values for Iran.

- IR
- IRN
- Iran

This will generate the following regular expressions:

- %[, "]IR[, "]% - Match any string which contains a word that start with a comma or space or quote ([, "]) and is then followed by IR and then end with either a comma or space or quote.
- %[, "]IRN[, "]% -  Match any string which contains a word that start with a comma or space or quote ([, "]) and is then followed by IRN and then end with either a comma or space or quote.
- %[, "]Iran[, "]% - Match any string which contains a word that start with a comma or space or quote ([, "]) and is then followed by Iran and then end with either a comma or space or quote.

To match the possibility that the country might be at the end of the string we include an additional `OR` condition where no pattern match is defined for the end. Similar to match the possibility that the country name might be at the start of the string we include an additional `OR` condition where no pattern match is defined for the start.

Comment: Thanks for this solution @Edmond! Works pretty well. Could you pls tell me how you've joined on `(T.BeneAddress LIKE '%[ ,]' + M.MatchIdentifier + '[, ]%')`. My sql's a bit weak, so couldn't get how joins work w/o the usual A.x = B.x. Also, then I cud try incorporating more conditions in the regex to handle scenarios like countryname in quotes or at start of string or if freetext has only country name nothing else - coz currently they don't return a match. Another issue I encountered is that it returns a match against payee names as well eg 'Mr bb Sudan' will return Barbados & Sudan both. Thx!

Comment: @V.Asher the join itself is really not much different to a traditional join except instead of performing an exact match between T.BeneAddres and M.MatchIdentifier it will instead join the T.BeneAddres when it matches the pattern as defined by the regular expression.
I will update the answer with an example on how to deal with quotes and country names at the start of the string with some additional explanation. Unfortunately, there is not a lot you can do about scenarios where the person’s name might also match a county name since the country name cab be at the start of the string or the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So if I understood you correctly: `(T.BeneAddress LIKE '%[ ,]' + M.MatchIdentifier + '[, ]%')` will join only if both fields contain **' ,'** and `(T.BeneAddress LIKE '%[, ]' + M.MatchIdentifier)` will join only if T.BeneAddress has it while M.MatchIdentifier doesn't? For the last bit you mentioned, for ~90% of the records, the country name is in the end. Cheers!

Comment: They will only join if both contains a space or a comma, in the update example I included quote which looks as follows [ ,"]. The square brackets means the string being compared must contain one of the characters (and only one) within the brackets. The following msdn article will probably explain it better than I can :)  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: This is great! I'll read through this msdn article now. Will use this script against real data and analyse the matches, hope fully this should give a good hit rate! I'll keep you posted of how it turns out! Cheers for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question.

The following will return the HIGHEST NUMBER OF MATCH HITS.  It does require a PARSING function listed below:

**Create Sample Data**

```
Declare @YouTable table (TransID int,ISOCode varchar(50),BeneAddress varchar(500))
Insert Into @YouTable values 
(20,'IRN','aaaa bb cccc Islamic Rupublic of Iran'),
(19,'IRN','aaaa bb cccc Iran, Islamic Republic of')

Declare @ISO table (ID int,ISONumericCode int,countryName varchar(50),matchIdentifier varchar(50),matchIdentifierType varchar(50))
Insert Into @ISO values
(209  ,364,'Iran, Islamic Republic of','IR',                       'ISOAlphaCode_2'),
(210  ,364,'Iran, Islamic Republic of','IRN',                      'ISOAlphaCode_3'),
(495  ,364,'Iran, Islamic Republic of','Iran',                     'Short_Name'),
(1163 ,364,'Iran, Islamic Republic of','Iran, Islamic Republic of','Original_Name'),
(1309 ,364,'Iran, Islamic Republic of','Islamic Rupublic of Iran' ,'Alternate_Name')
```

**Actual SQL**

```
;with cteBase as (
        Select A.*,B.*,C.*
            From  @YouTable A
            Cross Apply (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.BeneAddress,' ')  ) B
            Cross Apply (Select * from @ISO where matchIdentifier like '%'+B.RetVal+'%') C),    
      cteSumm as (
        Select TransID,ID,RowNr=Row_Number() over (Partition By TransID Order by Count(*) Desc)
        From cteBase
        Group By TransID,ID
)
Select B.*,C.*
 From  cteSumm A
 Join  @YouTable B on (A.RowNr=1 and A.TransID = B.TransID)
 Join  @ISO C      on (A.RowNr=1 and A.ID=C.ID)
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The UDF**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
```

Comment: Hi John, thank you for the solution..it works pretty well. The only issue with this is that it tries to match on every word in the BeneAddress like 'of', 'the' etc. eg. 'Mr.X People's Republic of China' will find a match with 'Iran, Islamic Republic of' due to the matching word 'of'.

Comment: @V.Asher Yes, but it is returning the top hit.   I'll noodle it a bit more.

Comment: Cheers @John. It might not be achievable, but could there be a way of having something like a percentage match i.e. if the free text 'Iran, Islamic Republic of' is match against the list of countries it'll have a higher match percentage with 'Iran' than with 'Iran, Islamic Republic of' than with 'People's Republic of China', if that makes sense?

Comment: Sorry, just re-read my comment it doesn't make sense. to rephrase - It might not be achievable, but could there be a way of having something like a percentage match i.e. if the free text _'Iran, Islamic Republic of'_ is matched against the list of countries, it'll have a higher match percentage with _'Iran, Islamic Republic of'_ than with _'People's Republic of China'_ since there is a match on 4 words compared to 2, if that makes sense?

Comment: @V.Asher It does, and I was going down that path.  On a call right now, but I will try to slip this in